# How to run an external script in SCons configure

Tags: python, scons

I have a script (Python) that check if I have the right modules installed and if they are up to date -- at least a certain version.  I want to run this script in the scons [Configure](http://www.scons.org/wiki/SconsAutoconf) phase.  I tried something like:

```
print 'Configuring... '
conf = Configure(env)
print 'Checking Python modules ', 
ret = conf.TryRun("""#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'ook' # test
import my_script
my_script.run()
""", '.py')
if ret == (0, ''):
    print 'Fail'
    sys.exit(2)
env = conf.Finish()
```

But all I get is `(0, '')` which means that TryRun failed but I cannot see why it would fail!   Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick but is not very elegant:

```
from subprocess import call
if call(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'my_script.py')):
    sys.exit(2)
```

I am still looking for a more elegant solution.